# Creating binary based on recurring ID within an array

Tags: php, arrays, binary

I have an array of image_IDs some are reoccurring. I want to group these with coloured rows (I am using bold just to see the effect). I cant use odd/even as the image_id might be even next to an even. Here is an example array;

> Array ( [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knSk8.jpg) => 9681 [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATAvm.jpg) => 9681 [3] => 9681 [4] => 8351 [5] => 8351
>   [6] => 8351 [7] => 2320 [8] => 2320 [9] => 2320 [10] => 2320 [11] =>
>   2320 [12] => 20711 [13] => 20711 [14] => 20711 [15] => 20711 [16] =>
>   5223 [17] => 5223 [18] => 5223 [19] => 5223 [20] => 5223 )

The idea would be the 9681s would be one colour then the 8351s would be another colour then the 2320s could restart the same colour as the 9681s. Creating a visible grouping of each image (based on image_ID). The Image _ID is the only thing that can be used to group the images.

SO the crux of the problem is how to group things in a list or array (if I have to convert between them I can) and apply an alternating format to each group. if that alternating format is binary that works for me, so the above would be "11100011111000011111" because I could use that in a loop to apply an if...else loop with some styling.

I have tried 
    if ($image_id & 2) {
    ... apply bold
    } else {
    ... do not bold 
    }

[image: table of images with tags]

// Here is the code I finally used thanks to @kainaw

```
// Create a binary pattern to match occurrence of image_id for visually grouping later 
// Create a new array to count the values then make the count the keys
$output_result_array['bin_group'] = array_flip(array_count_values($output_result_array['source']));
// Setup temp variables
$c = false;
$l = null;
// Loop though the counted and flipped array creating a binary representation of groups.    
foreach($output_result_array['source'] as $k=>$v) {
   if($v != $l) $c = !$c;
   $output_result_array['bin_group'][$k] = $c;
   $l = $v;
}
// START add different row colouring based on Image_id groups represented in BIN        
if ($output_result_array['bin_group'][$x]) {
$output_result .= '<tr class="post bg2;">';
}   else {
$output_result .= '<tr>';
}
// END add different row colouring
```

[image: Now with grouped row colouring]

Comment: You can't use 2 colors according to your description. I will use letters to make this far simpler. Assume I have ABCA. A is one color. B is the other. C goes back to A's color. Then, I have A again. I can't use A's color unless you can guarantee that A won't show up later on by, say, sorting the list before doing this.

Comment: If your array IDs are in order, all the 9681s together, simply detect when the ID changes and change the state of your highlighting.

Comment: @kainaw - If I have AABCCCAAA = I would like = RED:RED:BLUE:RED:RED:RED:BLUE:BLUE:BLUE it doesnt matter if another A turns up, the idea is to group visually only, between groups.

Comment: @Dave - in PHP I can detect a change but not a group. My reply to kainaw might help. This problem is doing my head in, its simple yet complex. I really appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: Added a screenshot of what the page looks like.  The idea is Map is 
 red, then Looking up the tube! is blue then  general view i red again. https://photos.app.goo.gl/Fw7CnRkHYjhuRY4v9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a Boolean array. That is easy enough. What I would do is create a separate array. Assume $a is your array. First, create a new array where the keys are the values of $a:

```
$b = array_flip($a);
```

Now, every value in $a is a key in $b. The values in $b are the counts of how many times each value appears in $a. We don't care.

The next step is to alternate a Boolean value. Start with it equal to whatever you don't want to start with. Then, invert it each time you use it.

```
$c = false;
foreach($b as $k=>$v) $b[$k] = $c = !$c;
```

You set $c equal to the negation of $c. That new value is passed into the binary array. You end up with an array where every key is your original values and every value is an alternating Boolean value.

How do you use it? Consider this. My original array is $a and $b is my boolean array.

```
foreach($a as $v) {
  if($b[$v]) print "$v is true.\n";
  else print "$v is false.\n";
}
```

If, instead of this, you only want a Boolean array. That is easy to do as well. Again, assume your original array is $a and the new Boolean array is $b. The key is storing the last value seen.

```
$b = array();
$c = false;
$l = null;
foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
  if($v != $l) $c = !$c;
  $b[$k] = $c;
  $l = $v;
}
```

Every time the last value doesn't match the new value, the Boolean value is flipped.

Comment: WOW you clever Hog! ;)  Thank you very much, I have worked it into my code, I wish I could show my workings here but there is a char limit..